# VBA - Creating, editing and sending non-visible email

Tags: outlook, display, inspector

I have some code that sends creates emails to send out weekly work assignments; it generates about 10 or so emails; each email contains  from 0 to 5 Excel tables, showing various assignments.

The code works great when the emails are set to .display while they are being created. 
However, when I turn .display off, the activeinspector that I use to manipulate the body of the email doesn't correctly identify&select the email object that I just created.

I can provide the code, but basically what I'm asking is, is there a way to manipulate the body of an email: 
a) without using .body (since I'm not using a simple string), and 
b) without using activeinspector

Or, is there a way that I can get activeinspector to consistently select the email that was just created, even though it is not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should really post the relevant snippets of your code. Secondly, use `MailItem.GetInspector` instead of `Application.ActiveInspector`.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry! using MailItem.GetInspector seems to have done the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!